# How to separate foreach values in different variables?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to separate `foreach` values in different vars.
I'm getting data from a API in json form and I echoed those values using `foreach`, And I want to print the echoed value in a `input value` using JavaScript I tried the below code but it prints the last value in the `foreach loop`.
My code:

```
<?php 
foreach ($movie['torrents'] as $torrents): 
    $torrents = get_object_vars($torrents); 
?>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2" onclick="addSizeToForm()">Try it</button>
    <script>
    function addSizeToForm() {
        document.getElementById("file_size").value = "<?php echo $torrents['size'];?>";
    }
    </script>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<input id="file_size" type="text" value="" required>
```

Thank You in advanced :)

Comment: you're producing invalid HTML/Javascript. The function `addSizeToForm` is declared multiple times. Have a look into the generated HTML...

Comment: Should I keep the `<Script>` tag outside the `foreach loop` or what? please provide me the code. @LarsStegelitz

Comment: `$torrents['size']` Gives 4-5 outputs, I want any of them to be putted on the Input field by just clicking a button, I can do it manually, but I got curious about how can I make it faster. @brombeer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is supply a value to your `addSizeToForm()` function:

```php
<?php 
foreach ($movie['torrents'] as $torrents): 
    $torrents = get_object_vars($torrents); 
?>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2" onclick="addSizeToForm('<?=$torrents['size']?>')">Try it</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<input id="file_size" type="text" value="" required>
<script>
function addSizeToForm(size) {
    document.getElementById("file_size").value = size;
}
</script>
```